# AWS access policy evaluation not allowing to put bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have the following policy attached to an IAM user:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:PutBucketCORS",
                "s3:DeleteBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutBucketNotification",
                "s3:PutBucketLogging",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "s3:PutAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetBucketLogging",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ReplicateTags",
                "s3:RestoreObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:PutBucketTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:PutMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner",
                "s3:PutBucketWebsite",
                "s3:PutBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetBucketCORS",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xyz123-mycloud-dump",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xyz123-mycloud-dump/SAMPLE/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:HeadBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now with the access credentials of the IAM user, that has the above policy attached to it, I am trying to run the following command:

```sh
s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket xyz123-mycloud-dump --policy file://policy.json
```

where the contents of the file *policy.json* is :

```json
{
    "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::<the_account_number_to_which_the_user_belongs>:user/<the_IAM_user_name>",
          "Action": "s3:*",
          "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::xyz123-mycloud-dump/SAMPLE/*", "arn:aws:s3:::xyz123-mycloud-dump"]
      }
    ]
}
```

and I get an

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketPolicy operation: Access Denied

Now I am trying to understand why?

The policy statement for the user allows `PutBucketPolicy` on the resources:

```
xyz123-mycloud-dump,
xyz123-mycloud-dump/SAMPLE/
```

and that's what I am trying to do with my policy above. Then why is the access being denied?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-bucket-policy/):

> To resolve the Access Denied error, check the following:
>
> - Your IAM identity has permissions for both s3:GetBucketPolicy and    s3:PutBucketPolicy.
> - The bucket policy doesn't deny your IAM identity
>   permission for s3:GetBucketPolicy or s3:PutBucketPolicy.
> - Your change to the bucket policy doesn't grant public access when Amazon S3 Block Public Access is enabled.
> - The AWS Organizations service control policy allows Amazon S3 access.
> - If the bucket policy denies everyone access to s3:GetBucketPolicy, s3:PutBucketPolicy, or all Amazon S3 actions (s3:*), then delete the bucket policy.

Check whether you have active Organization level SCPs that you are not aware of, or whether the Block Public Access is enabled.

Comment: Block Public Access is enabled. But I don't think that's a public access that the policies are trying to give there. The policy is simply trying to give * access to that specific IAM user. The rest of the points are all take care of.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the policy as you posted `policy.json`

I tried it gives me the error:

```json
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Id": "randome",
    "Statement":[
      {
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/username",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/random/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

```sh
$aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket mybucket --policy file://x.json

An error occurred (MalformedPolicy) when calling the PutBucketPolicy operation: Invalid policy syntax.
```

When I use the correct policy as per the documentation suggests;

[Bucket Policy Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

```json
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Id": "randome",
    "Statement":[
      {
        "Effect":"Allow",
       "Principal": {
          "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/username"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/random/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

It works

```sh
$ aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket mybucket --policy file://x.json
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: isn't the above policy missing a closing " ? @samtoddler

Comment: @qre0ct pardon me, that's a copy paste trouble. Updated

Comment: I changed the `Principal` to look like the `{ "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<the_account_number_to_which_the_user_belongs>:user/<the_IAM_user_name>"},` I added the `version` and the `id` attributes too.  
The results are no different.

Comment: @qre0ct check your credentials if they are what you want them to be using [sts  get-caller-identity](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html)

Comment: @samtodler the credentials are what I need. I am just trying to understand why is it not working, when it looks like it should.

Comment: @qre0ct as you mentioned you already have the necessary credentials, but still not able to update. I would check `cloudtrail` there must be the error why it is failing. Plus check your environment variable if there are other credentials still hanging.